# Database design ensure one to one relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, database-schema

I'm trying to understand the limitations of class table inheritance in database design. For instance if I have a schema like this how can I ensure that more than one row in school field table or non profit table does not reference the same contact id

```
Contact
--------
id - PK 
fname - String
lname - String
email - String

School Field
--------------
id - PK
contact_id - FK
notes - String

Non Profit Field
-----------------
id - PK
contact_id - FK
donation - unsigned int
```

Comment: So if a record in SchoolField references ID 1 in Contact, can a record in NonProfitField reference contactID 1?

Comment: Yeah that's okay if that happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend a different approach.

```
Entity
-------------- 
id - PK 
Field_Type_ID - FK 
contact_id - FK 
notes - String
donation - unsigned int (nullable)

Contact
-------------- 
id - PK 
fname- String
lname- String
email- String

Field_Type
-------------- 
id - PK 
Description- FK 
notes - String
```

By doing this, you will not need to add more tables if you end up with more "field" types. You just add a new record into the Field_Type table. Then to enforce your desired behavior, you add a unique constraint on Entity that looks at both contactID and FieldTypeID. That will ensure that each contact can be linked to a field type only once.

https://www.w3schools.com/sqL/sql_unique.asp

Comment: Can you expand on Description and notes in field type table? What does description reference and what does notes represent in the context of the field type table?

Comment: Description would be 'School' and 'NonProfit'. That way you would not need to make a new table in the event you get a new 'field' that you have to start tracking. Notes doesnt mean anything, I just copied it from your example.

Comment: So does that mean that an entity with a field_type_id = 'School' will have donation as null? How does the application knows which columns apply to which field type? so for instance if I'm adding a new row to the entity how do I know to only update notes for field type = 'school' and not donation